# Диалоговое окно "сохранить как" на php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, юзаю библиотеку генерации qr code на php. По нажатию на кнопку он появляется на экране. А мне нужно, чтобы появилось диалоговое окно "сохранить как" и я мог сохранить в qr code.
Вот код, что в него нужно дописать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку "Сгенерировать", чтобы появлялось диалоговое окно ?

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:**
    <?php

```
echo "<h1>Генератор QR Code</h1><hr/>";

//set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
$PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

//html PNG location prefix
$PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

include "qrlib.php";

//ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
    mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);

$filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';

//processing form input
//remember to sanitize user input in real-life solution !!!
$errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
if (isset($_REQUEST['level']) && in_array($_REQUEST['level'], array('L','M','Q','H')))
    $errorCorrectionLevel = $_REQUEST['level'];

$matrixPointSize = 4;
if (isset($_REQUEST['size']))
    $matrixPointSize = min(max((int)$_REQUEST['size'], 1), 10);

if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {

    //it's very important!
    if (trim($_REQUEST['data']) == '')
        die('data cannot be empty! <a href="?">back</a>');

    // user data
    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test'.md5($_REQUEST['data'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
    QRcode::png($_REQUEST['data'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);

} else {

    //default data

    QRcode::png('Привет:)', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);

}

//display generated file
echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';

//config form
echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">
    Введите, что хотите закодировать:&nbsp;<input name="data" value="'.(isset($_REQUEST['data'])?htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['data']):'Привет :)').'" />&nbsp;
    Коррекция ошибок:&nbsp;<select name="level">
        <option value="L"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='L')?' selected':'').'>L - smallest</option>
        <option value="M"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='M')?' selected':'').'>M</option>
        <option value="Q"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='Q')?' selected':'').'>Q</option>
        <option value="H"'.(($errorCorrectionLevel=='H')?' selected':'').'>H - best</option>
    </select>&nbsp;
    Размер:&nbsp;<select name="size">';

for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'"'.(($matrixPointSize==$i)?' selected':'').'>'.$i.'</option>';

echo '</select>&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" value="Сгенерировать"></form><hr/>';

    ?>
 <?
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qrcode.png'); // Прочитав этот         заголовок браузер выдаст пользователю диалог для сохранения файла на его компьютере
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); // Бинарная передача данных
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
  echo file_get_contents($filename);
  ?>
```

Comment: Не нужно ничего писать, все уже давно написано в браузере, правой кнопкой клик по изображению и выбираем "Сохранить"

Answer (score 5):

Перед отправкой картинки в браузер, отсылайте заголовки:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qrcode.png'); // Прочитав этот заголовок браузер выдаст пользователю диалог для сохранения файла на его компьютере
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); // Бинарная передача данных
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename)); // Здесь нужно указать размер картинки qr кода в байтах
```

Comment: плюс один )

Comment: Вот сделал, картинку сохраняет, но криво. Ее не открывает нигде.

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qrcode.png'); // Прочитав этот заголовок браузер выдаст пользователю диалог для сохранения файла на его компьютере
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); // Бинарная передача данных
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename)); // Здесь нужно указать размер картинки qr кода в байтах    
//display generated file
    echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';

Comment: Вы не понимаете, чего хотите сделать. Причем здесь HTML тэги?

Comment: Смотрите у меня показывает QR code - выводит на экран:
echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';
А мне нужно, чтобы он выводился и сохранялся на компьютере

Comment: ну так после того как qr code выводится напишите то что сказал товарищ @nolka
Только учтите, что после функций header не должно быть никаких echo и тп.

Comment: после вывода echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>'; идут еще echo, поэтому я вставил эти три строки в самый конец файла. И все равно результат тот же. Она показывает, что сохраняет файл qrcode.png, но при открытии его - выдает, что не может прочитать.

Comment: В коде вывода Вашей картинки после всех header должно быть только одно эхо и это:  

    echo file_get_contents($filename);

Comment: Должно быть только одно эхо на весь код, который отвечает за выдачу картинки. Этот код должен только отдавать картинку, и больше ничего. Никаких тэгов.  

    <?
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qrcode.png'); // Прочитав этот заголовок браузер выдаст пользователю диалог для сохранения файла на его компьютере
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); // Бинарная передача данных
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
    echo file_get_contents($filename);
    ?>